# Boot Ubuntu from external USB HDD on Retina MacBookPro 2015

Tags: boot, uefi, external-hdd, macbook-pro

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04/x86_64 on an external USB HDD, the disk has a GUID partition table, and the Ubuntu was installed with EFI boot manager.

I can successfully boot the USB HDD on some Windows PCs in UEFI mode, but it doesn't work on my new Retina MacBook Pro 2015 model (MacBookPro11,5), when I reboot the computer with "Option" key pressed, the boot entry simply didn't show up.

It's a bit weird that my RMBP does support UEFI 2.0, it can boot  Windows8/10 from external HDD in EFI mode. I've no idea why Ubuntu doesn't work.

Comment: Do not know Mac. But Ubuntu on a PC only installs boot loaders to drive seen as sda. I have tried installing to an ESP on my sdb drive and it says it is installing to sdb, but overwrites my /efi/ubuntu folder in sda. Do you have an /EFI/ubuntu folder in your external drive? And external drives in UEFI use /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. That file may be a copy of Windows own /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmfgw.efi file. You can copy shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot and rename it to bootx64.efi. But it will use a tiny grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu which is just a configfile to find the real grub.cfg in your install.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. When you hold down the option key at startup, the firmware does not look at the EFI partition. One reason is that this partition is FAT formatted. Another, is the files and directories have the wrong names and folder structure.

Comment: As a person who already has ubuntu installed on an external disk on a Mac, let me ask you: How do you what to boot ubuntu? Do you want to use Grub 2 or boot directly to ubuntu? Do you want to use rEFInd as a boot manager? Do you want to just use `bless` to switch booting to ubuntu? It is not a question of how to do it, but rather which way do you prefer.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I just want to boot a EFI Ubuntu installation I've made on another machine on an external USB HDD, don't want to bother with rEFIt or rEFInd.

Comment: AFAIK, no Mac supports EFI 2.x (aka UEFI). This is confusing because Apple's internal version number has exceeded 2.0, but it's still following EFI 1.x standards in many areas, so it's not really EFI 2.x/UEFI. I have a late 2014 MacBook Air with firmware that reports itself as "Apple 1.10," for instance. That said, Apple has incorporated some EFI 2.x/UEFI features in its firmware, so it's really something of a hybrid.

Comment: @Rod: I have never used "EFI Boot ROM version" to determine if a Mac supports UEFI. I have used the file given in Update 2 of my answer given below.

Comment: David, that's just a file on your computer's filesystem. As such, it does not directly identify your firmware. Furthermore, you're *assuming* that models that are not in the "PreUEFIModels" list *do* use UEFI. In Ubuntu, you can learn the firmware's version by doing `dmesg | grep EFI`, which displays the kernel's firmware query. Among the output lines will normally be one with the EFI revision, as in `efi: EFI v1.10 by Apple`. You can also get the information in an EFI shell or in some boot loaders. My rEFInd shows this information in its "About" screen, for instance.

Comment: @Rod: I have had rEFInd installed in its own small partition on my Mac for sometime now. I never noticed the "About" screen until now. I guess my theory that the Info.plist could be used to determine if a Mac had a UEFI or could boot Windows in EFI/GPT mode is wrong. I make this conclusion based on what has been posted here, even though Apple never made a MacBook Air in late 2014 and a MacBook Pro early 2013 is not the same as a MacBookPro11,1. I would be interested what Windoze gets if he enters `dmesg | grep EFI` in a Ubuntu Terminal window.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, just checked, it shows "EFI v1.10 by Apple", looks even the newest MacBook Pro still doesn't have complete EFI 2.x support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, kind of stupid but I managed to make the external USB HDD boot.
Ubuntu installs the EFI boot files under "EFI/ubuntu" by default, simply rename it to "BOOT", and copy "grubx64.efi" to "bootx64.efi" then everything works as expected.

According comments from @RodSmith, above solution works as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` is the fallback name where EFI finds a bootloader.

It could be very useful if someone can explain Apple EFI behaviors in details.

Comment: You do not explain where you found the this answer. I found this site: [UEFIBooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting).

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I've found some info by random searching over the internet, don't remember if the page you mentioned is in the list, also tried a lot of modify-and-reboot cycles :lol:

Comment: A standard Ubuntu installation stores its boot loader at `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` on the ESP and creates an NVRAM entry for that name. When you move the disk to another computer, the NVRAM entry will be missing on the new computer, so this won't work. The `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` name is a fallback filename that's used to make bootable removable disks (OS installers, emergency utilities, etc.). EFIs are supposed to look to this name if no other EFI entries work or if the user requests a boot from an external medium.

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct. This will help others with the same problem find your solution. If someone posts a better answer, you can always change the one marked correct. Also, if you are interested, I did post where in the UEFI specification your answer can be found.

Answer (score 1):

When Windows 10 - 64 bit boots in EFI mode, the file the firmware loads is located at `/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` in the hidden EFI partition. Basically you moved and renamed grub 2 to this location and name. Your Mac thinks it is booting Windows when in fact it is boot grub 2. This is not because you have a new Retina MacBook Pro 2015 model (MacBookPro11,5). This also working for me and I have a iMac 2007 model (iMac7,1).

### Update 1:

I admit the above post is badly worded. When I refered to Windows 10, I was looking at an installation done in EFI mode using VirtualBox on my 2007 iMac. Rod's comment is correct, both `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` and `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` exist and are identical. I am not sure which file VirtualBox uses to boot the virtual machine.

I have Windows 8.1 - 64 bit installed on my iMac even though Apple's web site "[System requirements to install Windows on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048)" specifies only Windows 7 - 32 bit. This installation uses the legacy BIOS/MBR scheme.

The point I was trying to make was that Windoze's solution to booting Ubuntu (via GRUB 2) has nothing to do with having a UEFI compliant Mac. I successfully tested his method to boot Ubuntu installed on my internal hard disk. *This fact my be of interest to other Mac users.*

As for a detail explanation of why this method works for Windoze's case, I refer to the the [Unified Extensible Firmware Interface
Specification](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%202_5.pdf), Version 2.5, April, 2015. Section **3.5.1.1 Removable Media Boot Behavior**, on pages 88-89, specifies for the x64 architecture the firmware will attempt to boot from removable media using the file located at `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.EFI`.

### Update 2:

This is in response to Ron's comment about Mac's not being UEFI compliant.

When determining if a Mac has an UEFI, I look at the file `/Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app/Contents/Info.plist`. Below is a listing taken from my Mac with Yosemite OS X 10.10.4 and Boot Camp Assistant version 5.1.4 (500) installed. Specifically, I am looking at the array listed after the key `PreUEFIModels`. I have assumed that if a Mac model is later than one given in the array, Windows can and should be installed in EFI/GPT mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>32BitSupportedModels</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacBook7,1</string>
        <string>MacBookAir5,2</string>
        <string>MacBookPro10,1</string>
        <string>MacPro5,1</string>
        <string>Macmini5,3</string>
        <string>iMac12,2</string>
    </array>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>14D81</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Boot Camp Assistant</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Boot Camp Assistant</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Boot Camp Assistant 5.1.4, Copyright © 2015 Apple Inc. All rights reserved</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>DA</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.bootcampassistant</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Boot Camp Assistant</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>5.1.4</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>500</string>
    <key>DARequiredROMVersions</key>
    <array>
        <string>IM41.0055.B08</string>
        <string>IM42.0071.B03</string>
        <string>IM51.0090.B03</string>
        <string>IM52.0090.B03</string>
        <string>IM61.0093.B01</string>
        <string>MP11.005C.B04</string>
        <string>MB11.0061.B03</string>
        <string>MBP11.0055.B08</string>
        <string>MBP12.0061.B03</string>
        <string>MM11.0055.B08</string>
    </array>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>6D504m</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>14D77</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.10internal</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0630</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>6D504m</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.utilities</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.9.0</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>PreESDRequiredModels</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacBook7</string>
        <string>MacBookAir5</string>
        <string>MacBookPro10</string>
        <string>MacPro5</string>
        <string>Macmini6</string>
        <string>iMac13</string>
    </array>
    <key>PreUEFIModels</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacBook7</string>
        <string>MacBookAir5</string>
        <string>MacBookPro10</string>
        <string>MacPro5</string>
        <string>Macmini6</string>
        <string>iMac13</string>
    </array>
    <key>PreUSBBootSupportedModels</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacBook7,1</string>
        <string>MacBookAir3,2</string>
        <string>MacBookPro8,3</string>
        <string>MacPro5,1</string>
        <string>Macmini4,1</string>
        <string>iMac12,2</string>
    </array>
    <key>Win7OnlyModels</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacBook7,1</string>
        <string>MacBookAir3,2</string>
        <string>MacBookPro5,5</string>
        <string>MacPro2,1</string>
        <string>Macmini4,1</string>
        <string>iMac10,1</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you sure your 2007 iMac can boot Windows in EFI mode correctly? AFAIK Mac supports UEFI 2 since later 2013, I've tried to install Windows 8 with EFI on a MacBook Pro early 2013(MacBookPro11,1) and it didn't work, had to use to BIOS/Hybrid mode.

Comment: The `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` name is *not* the Windows boot loader name; that boot loader's official name is `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. That said, Microsoft tends to *copy* its boot loader to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`, which is the fallback filename. Presumably Microsoft does this because there are a lot of flaky EFIs and circumstances in which the NVRAM entry can be lost, so having a boot loader at `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` is helpful insurance. Another boot program can easily (and legally) take that name, though.